# Scrape entire xml page within R, relenium

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

Trying to scrape a page similar to the link below, where the page doesn't load all of the results right away - it waits for you to scroll to the end of the page before loading more results.  Thus, when the code below runs, it only picks up the results that have loaded so far (16 out of 20,000 in this example).

https://www.rbauction.com/search?id=ar&region=Europe&s=YXI3fE49NDI5NDk1NzE5MCs0Mjk0MjM4MzMy

Using this basic code for now:

```
require(relenium)
require(XML)
firefox=firefoxClass$new()
url="https://www.rbauction.com/search?id=ar&region=Europe&s=YXI3fE49NDI5NDk1NzE5MCs0Mjk0MjM4MzMy"
url=sprintf(url)
firefox$get(url)
doc=htmlParse(firefox$getPageSource())
title=xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@class='display-text']",xmlValue)
title
```

This only produces the first 16 "titles" on the webpage (there are over 20,000).  Any ideas?

Don

Answer (score 1):

Saw this query while searching for something else here. Not sure if its too late to answer. I had a similar challenge recently for another website. The trick in this case is to find the element in the source which mimics the scroll down action and click it using relenium. I couldn't access the above link, so I am going to demonstrate my example.

Sample url: http://www.snapdeal.com/products/computers?sort=plrty&

The above page displays only 15/20 products at a time. The below code mimics the scroll down action

Code:

> firefox$get("http://www.snapdeal.com/products/computers?sort=plrty&")
>
> buttonElement <- firefox$findElementByXPath("//*[@id='seeMoreProducts']")
>
> buttonElement$click()

You just need to put this in a loop and repeat depending on the total number of results and results displayed in one go.

Do note that as the number of results increase and you continue to scroll down, all the data will continue to be on the page which will make this a very slow process.

Ultimately, I found an alternative where I was able to understand the changed url of the different pages. While they may not show in the address bar, the actual url was changing. Just explore the source and you should be able to find it.